# Laravel, Eloquent, Carbon adding hours issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

On one of my models I use `created_at` data to calculate a value for a different filed called expires.. Carbon does the operation.. The code is something like this

```
$membership = New Persons;
$membership->approver = 123;
$membership->receiver = 7;
$membership->plan = 'gold';
$membership->save();

$expires = clone $membership->created_at;
$expires->addHours(72);

$membership->expires = $expires;
$membership->save();
```

The operation works out OK except for the hours added are not 72..

My created_at time is **2015-01-13 20:43:44** and my expires value is **2015-01-17 01:43:43** while it should be **2015-01-16 20:43:44**

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

It makes use of eloquent events to set the 'expires' attribute of your `persons` model and more importantly, avoids the round-trip of doing another `save()` operation on your model.

```
class Persons extends eloquent {
    /*
    * Model events
    */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function($model){
            $model->expires = Carbon::now()->addHours(72);
        });
    }
}
```

If your expires attribute depends on other factors, use the following accessor rather than saving it to the database.

```
class Persons extends eloquent {
    //this appends the expires virtual attribute to your model.
    //This attribute is not saved to the DB
    protected $appends = array('expires');

    //Expires accessor
    public function getExpiresattribute()
    {
        return $this->updated_at->addHours(72);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmh,, I will give this a go to see how it affects the creation of times. I have to see if it is viable in terms of what I need for the overall app functionality. My expires value will have to also update with the change of updated_at in other places in app nd there are other considerations towards how expires is created and changed. Generally speaking, regardless of my app, this is an interesting idea.

Comment: In that case, you are better off using an `accessor` function with a virtual attribute. If a `persons`' children is updated, the `persons` updated_at timestamp can be automatically updated as well: see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#touching-parent-timestamps